# Google Chart API Data

Tags: php, mysql, api, google-visualization

How do I populate the Google Chart API with my own Server side data i.e. in PHPMySQL.

Currently I have the following data:

```
function drawChart()
{
 // Create the data table.
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'City');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Crimes');
 data.addRows([
             ['Cardiff', 300],
             ['London', 900],
             ['Manchester', 500],
             ['Dublin', 400],
             ['Liverpool', 600]
             ]);

// Set Chart Options
var options = {
    'legend': 'left',
    'title': 'Crimes (per day)',
    'is3D': 'True',
    'width':400,
    'height':300
};

// Instantiate and Draw Chart.
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

But how do I feed it the data from a table in my mySQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the JavaScript-Code of the Charts API you have to get your data out of your database:

```
//Your database query goes here
$list = mysql_query("SELECT city,crimes FROM TABLE");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
  $data[] = "['".$row['city']."', ".$row['crimes']."]";
}
$data_for_chart = implode(",\n"$data);
```

Now replace in your JS-code:

```
data.addRows([
         ['Cardiff', 300],
         ['London', 900],
         ['Manchester', 500],
         ['Dublin', 400],
         ['Liverpool', 600]
         ]);
```

With:

```
data.addRows([
         <?php echo $data_for_chart; ?>
         ]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you tell me where ? I'm really not good with this.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I've expanded my answer.