# Unable to create a google pie chart from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Reading through several posts, I have got the basic idea of creating google charts but I am still not clear with how it is created from data extracted from tables in DB. Some json parsing of objects is done, but not clear with it. I have written some code. Please provide me with some direction ahead.

//chartDraw.php

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>">
<script type="text/javascript">
//Load the visualization API and the piechart package
google.load('visualization','1',{'packages':['corechart']});
//Set a callback to run when the google visualization API is loaded
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);
function drawChart(){
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url:"getdata.php",
        dataType:"json",
        async:false
        }).responseText;
//Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server
var data=new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
//Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
var chart=new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data,{width:400,height:240});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <!--Div that will hold the pie chart -->
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

//getdata.php specified in the url property

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','uname','123456');
mysql_select_db('rcusers');

$sqlquery1="select userid,group_name,req_nodes,actualPE from jobs where userid='zhang' limit 200";

$sqlresult1=mysql_query($sqlquery1);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult1)){
        $userDetails[]=$row;

}

?>
```

What next and How am I supposed to send the data to json objects and where? I am confused..

Comment: which database values have you to show on pie chart..???

Comment: you need to manipulate your json data to the correct format see google charts api for some examples https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples

Comment: this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979987/google-chart-api-data?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple example may be help you

```
<html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#test').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'fetch_data.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
               var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['T', result[0]],
                  ['W', result[1]],
                  ['E', result[2]]

                ]);

                var options = {
                  title: 'My Daily Activities'
                };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        });
       });
      });
       </script>
      </head>
     <body>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        <a href="#" id="test">click</a>
     </body>
    </html>
```

fecth_data.php

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect('localhost','akshita','123456');
mysql_select_db('rcusers');

$sqlquery1="select userid,group_name,req_nodes,actualPE from jobs where userid='zhang' limit 200";

$sqlresult1=mysql_query($sqlquery1);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult1)){
        $data[]="['".$row['group_name']." ', ".$row['req_nodes']." ', ".$row['actualPE']."]";
}
$data_for_chart=implode(",\n"$data);

Comment: @Yogesh: I have added json_encode to convert it into json format but no output. Please help!

Comment: @Yogesh: I have added json_encode to convert it into json format but no output. Please help!...Here is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073654/unable-to-extract-data-to-get-google-chart-nothing-is-being-displayed-but-getda/15073745#comment21199390_15073745

Comment: Can you please help me with my code. Its not working. i entered json_encode is json_encode($userDetails);

Comment: Complete code- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073654/unable-to-extract-data-to-get-google-chart-nothing-is-being-displayed-but-getda/15073745#comment21199390_15073745