# Sorting and pulling scores from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures

I'm developing a sort of game site where every members score is saved for each day. Now I have a database with a table for user information and a table for user score. The **user_score** table contains:

> ID | User_ID |  Points |  Day

Every day the user gets their graph updated in their personal part of the homepage. The graph shows the users score for each day, with a yAxes displaying the highest score in the top of the graph. I need to emphasis that the graph displays the users own score only, like a form curve for that specific user.

My issue is that I want to display the users position in the ranking system in the graph, not their score...

So my question would be: What do I change in order to give the user his positions not the score? I was trying to add another table in the database to sort this out, but it seems like a pickle.

Should I add another table, should I do anything special in my query? 
Im using Google Chart API, and trying to follow another [thread to make the PHP connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979987/google-chart-api-data)

Comment: You can use http://redis.io or similar database for storing per day ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this..

```
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from `user_score` order by Points desc");
 // Store the user Id in $userid variable of the user whose position you want to show
 $position=0;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
    $position+=1;
    if($row['User_ID']==$userid)
       break;
 }

 echo $position; // here you got the position of that user.
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that, it worked for day 1, but now I need to update the rest of the 4 days in the form curve